# MySQL query for each subgroup

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
Year Month    Code
1850 January  5210
1850 February 3524
1851 January  6752
1851 January  9877
1851 February 3698
```

I want to delete repeated months within a year (e.g. 1851 January). I don´t mind loosing one code (6752 or 9877). I thought of using:

```
Select * from table1 group by Month
```

But I need to group for each year. Otherwise I will select only one January from the three in the table, and I need to select two of them (one in 1850 and one in 1851).
Of course my table is huge and I cannot do it manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have only the entries with count>1 then you can do this:

```
Select year, month, code, count(1) as cnt from table1 group by year, month having cnt>1;
```

If the table is huge, make sure that both `year` and `month` are indexes, otherwise you'll spend lot of time waiting for results.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb325/3

UPDATE: for the case where there are more than 2 rows (and actually in general, if you don't care about the lost "code" entries), it might make sense to select one entry from each year-month into a new table (which will leave you with unique year-month combinations) and then discard the old table, like that:

```
CREATE TABLE table1_temp SELECT year, month, MIN(code) as code FROM table1 GROUP BY year, month;
DROP TABLE table1;
RENAME TABLE table1_temp TO table1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/113954/1

Comment: `SELECT *` combined with `GROUP BY` is a dangerous habit.

Comment: This is better. I'd use `Select year, month, MIN(code) AS code, ...` for the query to be working in all SQL modes but this is ok.

Comment: Query suggested by @Ashalynd will work if there are only 2 duplicate rows but it will not work if there are 3 or more rows for year 1951 and month January

Comment: right, things are much easier than that. see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Query suggested by @Ashalynd will work if you have only 2 duplicate rows but it will not work if you have 3 rows for year 1951 and month January ...Below query will take care it. You can remove all rows getting from below query.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT b.CODE 
FROM 
(SELECT YEAR, MONTH, CODE, COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM table1 GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH HAVING cnt>1) a, 
table1 b 
WHERE a.year=b.year AND a.month=b.month AND a.code<>b.code;
```

Another approach can be AS per below-

```
CREATE TABLE table1_new LIKE table1;ALTER TABLE table1_new ADD UNIQUE KEY (YEAR,MONTH);INSERT IGNORE INTO table1_new SELECT * FROM table1;
TRUNCATE TABLE table1;INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table1_new;
DROP TABLE table1_new;
```

Note: IF you want TO keep your VALUES UNIQUE based ON these FIELDS THEN CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON your main table.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Select *, count(month) as cnt from table1 group by Year, Month;
```

You will get all the months under the different years and either one of the repeating months eliminated.

[this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb325/2)

Comment: `SELECT *` combined with `GROUP BY` is a dangerous habit.

Comment: yes, sir, is there a way to get all the fields and use a group by too ?

Comment: Yes, there is. But your query returns indeterminate results. It may even return rows that do not exist on the table (combining values from multiple rows into one.)